# Trie implementation with using map

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Easy way for realize Trie data structure are use `std::map<char,*NodeTrie>`. What can happens wrong if I use that. I need serialize and deserialize Trie. So each map in the node is AVL- tree. Maybe I'll have overhead? But in map I can search faster, that if I use list.

```
template < typename T >
struct NodeTrie{
    std::map<char,*NodeTrie>`
    bool isWord;
    T & val;
};
```

Comment: do you have some data structure akin to hashmap? you can use that for minimal overhead. Or if not, then think about mapping a char to something more manageable

Comment: I need exactly Trie, for lexical search.

Comment: Instead of using std::map use std::unordered_map or something akin to that internally. That is what I was suggesting

Comment: So is your question "Should I use a `std::map<>` when implementing my trie nodes? (It *looks* like it, but...)

Comment: Yes, it is too bad? or normal? Will I have problems with Serialize Trie ? So if I deserialize map, I must push(and each time when i push node in map I get O(logn).

Comment: What makes you thing search would be faster with maps? Big Oh notation can easily be misleading for small data sets (such as 255 or fewer keys).

Comment: What is the size of the input alphabet ? I see that you use a char but is it much less than 255 ? For example, if you use only English it will be 26 and by a single pass through the inputs you can pre-compute the list of chars that matter and have a much simpler implementation.

Comment: @Ubitso Those 700000 keys are what the trie as a whole deals with. Inside each `NodeTrie`'s map, you only have `char` keys, i.e. at most 255 keys and most likely far less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your idea. Tries are important data structures, and I had pleasant experience with map<>s as efficient containers.

Just some remarks: if your compiler support it, you could avoid wasting memory with a separate allocation for each node.

```
template< typename T >
struct NodeTrie {
    NodeTrie(const T& val = T(), bool isWord = bool() ) : val(val), isWord(isWord) {}

    std::map<char, NodeTrie> span;
    T val;
    bool isWord;
};
```

To be used this way:

```
int main() {
    typedef NodeTrie<int> iTree;
    iTree t(0);
    t.span['a'] = iTree(3);
    ...
}
```

Also I changed the `val` member to be a copy constructible object: using a reference  here seems wrong design to me...

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, GNU libc++ has a trie template already in its policy based data structure library. You can use it like:

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/trie_policy.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace pb_ds;

trie <string, int> myTrie;
```

For some examples in using this class you can refer to [this](http://nesl.ee.ucla.edu/fw/han/old_machine_backup/overo-oe/tmp/work/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/gcc-cross-4.3.3-r12.1/gcc-4.3.3/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/ext/pb_ds/example/trie_prefix_search.cc).